# Scroll when all elements on page have position absolute?

Tags: html, css

On my page all elements have position absolute.
Some of them are on top and some on bottom side of page.
But when i add one additional element, to show news text, on center of page, it hides under the element which on aligned bottom. And on scrolling, element which aligned on bottom, it remains on the same place and the median continues to go down.
But I need, when page is scrollable, the bottom element is always stuck to the bottom.

```css
.top-element {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.middle-element {
  position: absolute;
  top: 300px;
  left: 0;
}
.bottom-element {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-element">MUCH TEXT IS HERE</div>
<div class="middle-element">MUCH TEXT IS HERE</div>
<div class="bottom-element">MUCH TEXT IS HERE</div>
```

If middle element content height is more than window size, bottom-element remains on the same place.

Comment: You should provide some code here so we can reproduce the problem

Comment: bottom: 0; should make it always at the bottom. Give us some code.

Comment: Absolute positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You should change `postion: absolute` to `fixed` of the bottom element